# How to stop Apache from running a local web server on Boot?

Tags: web-server, apache-httpd

I tried using this `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop`, but it only temporarily works and the server starts working again after a reboot. Is there a disable feature or something similar?

Comment: Upvote for being the #1 response from Google I searched on `raspbian disable apache2` (June 2018).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To stop a service doesn't prevent the deamon to start the service on boot. For this you should deactivate the service to come up on all run levels

A simple command for this on raspbian is
`update-rc.d apache2 disable`
If you later want the webserver starts again on default just type 
`update-rc.d apache2 enable`'

With the comand `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start` you bring up the web server on demand.

Comment: Upvote.  If the Pi is busy and should not be rebooted, the service can be stopped immediately with `sudo service apache2 stop`

Comment: @SDsolar, great addition! If thats fail, last option could kill the process. But this should not the way stopping a process.

Comment: I just used your `sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable` on several of my Pi3 data loggers that are in operation 24x7.  They had apache2 because I had enabled it on the first one before I began cloning them.  I don't reboot them unless necessary.  They produce what ultimately gets out on the web at http://www.SDsolarBlog.com/montage - among their other duties.  So I followed your procedure then stopped the service.  All finished now, and prepared for the next eventual reboot.  Thank you much for this tip.